# Firebase Cloud Function error due to EAI_AGAIN to identitytoolkit.googleapis.com

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have cloud functions running for months and suddenly all functions that rely on firebase authentication hit this error:

> 'Error while making request: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
> identitytoolkit.googleapis.com identitytoolkit.googleapis.com:443.
> Error code: EAI_AGAIN'

My firebase is on Blaze (pay) plan.

Redeploying the functions also fail with this message:

> Function deployment failed due to a health check failure. This usually
> indicates that your code was built successfully but failed during a
> test execution. Examine the logs to determine the cause. Try deploying
> again in a few minutes if it appears to be transient.

I would like to know if there is a resolution. Thank you!

Comment: Contact Firebase support directly if you think there is a problem with the service. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your reply! I just file an outage report to Firebase.

Comment: I was facing issues with authentication and cloud functions. There is a service disruption with Google App Engine. Follow https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/20007 for more details on status

Comment: @singhnikhil Thank you for your reply. I should have noticed that my cloud functions that do not use Firebase Authentication are not been affected.

Comment: Looks like the issue is resolved as of 9:17AM PST, my Google Cloud app is able to make an outbound request without EAI_AGAIN Issues. Thanks, @singhnikhil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DETAILS**

I am also experiencing this issue, (although I don't use Firebase, I use Google Cloud Platform, and a Node app running on Google Cloud's "App Engine").

I called Google Cloud support and they acknowledged there was some issue; no ETA or workaround yet. Google Cloud support said they would email me a link where I can check status of the issue; <strike>I'll post here when I have it.</strike> Here is the [general link](https://status.cloud.google.com) to Google Cloud Status dashboard, note the [specific Google Cloud issue #20007](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/20007) likely affecting us this morning, in `us-central1` region; their page doesn't mention `EAI_AGAIN` errors, but I bet those are related (and maybe affecting Firebase too)

[image: image showing status.cloud.google.com, which confirms some issue is affecting Google App Engine apps as of 10/6/2020 9AM PST]

(I tried workarounds like [increasing `process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/761#issuecomment-311251914), but it didn't work -- this issue *just* started affecting our apps this morning, and our apps do *not* make "many requests" (i.e. that I should queue the the requests), our app only makes a few requests -- so I haven't tried queueing yet)

**EDIT 10/6/2020 9:17AM PST**

Looks like the issue is resolved as of 9:17AM PST, my Google Cloud app is able to make an outbound request without EAI_AGAIN Issues. Thanks, @JoeLeung and @singhnikhil.

[image: Google Cloud issue 20007 is resolved as of 9:17AM PST]

Comment: I received an email from Firebase support team and they said it is an ongoing issue and Google engineers are fixing it. 

Being wake up in the early morning and dig into error logs without any clue until an hour later Google health status page shows the error message.

Comment: @JoeLeung , it looks like the issue was resolved at 9:17 AM PST (~ 10 minutes ago), is your Firebase Cloud Function working now?

Comment: Yes, my service was back online around 08:45 PDT. We may need to come up with a contingency plan for such a long outage though.

Comment: Just got this error again today. Very annoying.

Comment: i have same issue when fixing data error thats a lot of request to firebase notification in one time process.